# How to allow images but deny everything else?

Tags: nginx

The file structure is

1. LargerProject

   - Discord-OAuth2

     - config <-- don't want anyone to access this
     - static <-- images in here

When I don't include the bottom 2 location rules, my images show up, but my configs are accessible.  When I put the following rules (I've tried many variations), my images return with a 404 and my configs return with a 403.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        root /var/www/html/LargerProject;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ^~ /Discord-OAuth2/static/ {
        allow all;
    }

    location ^~ /Discord-OAuth2/ {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

None of the images are showing up on my site (flask server using Jinja)
I would like the images to show and the configs to return a 403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every location should be well defined action.

on ~ regexp match location, the longer path will match first.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        root /var/www/html/LargerProject;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location ^~ /Discord-OAuth2/static/ {
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        root /var/www/html/LargerProject;
    }

    location ^~ /Discord-OAuth2/ {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing!  Thank you!